# Find the $v$ that minimizes the integral $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)\text{log}\frac{p(x)}{g(x,v)}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

**Problem**: I have an integral of the form

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)\text{log}\frac{p(x)}{g(x,v)}dx$$

and I want to find the $v$ that minimizes it.

In particular, $p(x)$ and $g(x,v)$ are PDFs, where

$$p(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2}$$
and
$$g(x,v)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-2)^2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-v)^2},$$

and of course $\int p(x) dx=1$ and $\int g(x,v) dx=1$.

I know that the solution is around $v=0.55$ from numerical approximations but I can't seem to get to that answer analytically.

I'm trying to approach this problem from a variational calculus perspective. In this problem, we can only vary $g(x,v)$ and in fact we can really only vary the value of $v$. So I set up a functional with the constraint on $g$:

$$J[g]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)\text{log}\frac{p(x)}{g(x,v)}+\lambda g(x,v)dx,$$
and accordingly the Euler-Lagrange equation for $g$ is:

$$\frac{\delta J}{\delta g}=\frac{-p(x)}{g(x,v)}+\lambda=0$$

The first equation suggests (correctly, generally speaking) that $p=g$. However this doesn't help me much as in our example, $g$ cannot take on the form $p$ for any $v$.

My next attempt was to directly take $\frac{\delta J}{\delta g}=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$ since we can only change $v$. Then:

$$\frac{\delta J}{\delta g}=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}=\frac{p(x)g_v(x,v)}{g(x,v)}+\lambda g_v(x,v)=0$$

However this just turns out to be $p(x)g_v(x,v)=g(x,v)\lambda g_v(x,v)$ which implies the same thing, that $p=g$.

I don't really know how to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

**Note**: beyond this one problem, it would be ideal to have a solution for a general $$p(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{x_i \in X}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-x_i)^2}$$
and
$$g(x,v)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{x_i \in W}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-x_i)^2}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-v)^2}$$

Comment: Since $\ln[p(x)/g(x,v)] = \ln p(x) - \ln g(x,v)$, it is equivalent to maximize $\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)\ln g(x,v)dx$.

Comment: Yes, true, I tried to do it that way too. I still ended in the same result though...

Comment: You want to work with the gradient/derivative of $J$ with respect to the free parameter $v$.

Comment: Also there’s no need for the constraint, it’s baked in.

Comment: The general case will end up with integrals of the form $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-u^2/2)/[\sum a_i\exp( b_i u )]du$. Not sure how doable those are.

Comment: _...Solution is around $=0.55$...??_

Comment: Apologies I meant $v=0.55$, I have corrected that in the question

Comment: @Aruralreader thank you! I find that indeed solving $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(p(x) \text{log} \frac{p(x)}{g(x,v)} \right) dx=0$ does give $v=0.55..$ (using the Leibniz integral rule to move the partial inside)

Comment: @Aruralreader that technique is just partial differentiation, nothing to do with the calculus of variations. I was wondering, is there a variational calculus way of arriving at the same result? Why doesn't using the Euler-Lagrange equations work?

Comment: Using variational calculus for this seems fundamentally misguided to me. You're optimizing a function of a single variable, not a functional – what makes you think that variational calculus might be applicable to this problem?

Comment: If we replace $1$ and $2$ in the initial case with the general parameters $x_1$ and $x_2$, I can show that $v = x_2/2 + f(x_1-x_2)$, where $f$ is a single-variable function given implicitly by an integral equation. Would this be helpful?

Comment: @eyeballfrog yes that would be useful! Can you let me know how to derive that?

Comment: @joriki I guess the way I though of it is that we are trying to minimize the integral (which is a functional) with respect to a function in the integral ($g$), which is the setup for variational calculus. However, we have a restriction on $g$, in that we can only change the shape of $g$ by varying $v$ inside it, i.e. $g$ is restricted to a certain set of functions given by all possible values of $v$ plugged in.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on my comment, differentiating with respect to $v$ and setting equal to $0$ gives
$$
-\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)\frac{\partial_v g(x,v)}{g(x,v)}dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x-v}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^{-(x-x_1)^2/2}e^{-(x-v)^2/2}}{e^{-(x-x_2)^2/2} + e^{-(x-v)^2/2}}dx = 0
$$
This is a pretty spicy integral, but the shift $x\rightarrow u + (v+x_2)/2$ can get it into a nicer form. Making this substitution and defining $a = x_1-x_2$ and $b = (v-x_2)/2$ gives
$$
\frac{e^{-(a-b)^2/2}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty(u-b)e^{-u^2/2}\operatorname{sech}(b u)e^{a u}du = 0.
$$
Since the constant term outside the integral is always nonzero, this condition requires that the integral itself be zero.

That's about the best I could do, as the integral doesn't show up in any table I could find and it doesn't convert to a differential equation easily. However, this integral equation does implicitly define a function. That is, there is some single variable function $f$ such that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty[u-f(a)]e^{-u^2/2}\operatorname{sech}[f(a) u]e^{a u}du = 0
$$
is satisfied for all $a$. There may be some trickery using implicit differentiation and integration by parts to turn that integral into a differential equation for $f$, but I was unable to find any. At any rate, in terms of this function, we have
$$
v = x_2 + f(x_1-x_2).
$$

Comment: Thanks @eyeballfrog! So if I am to interpret it correctly, the integral representing $b$ contains the term $v$? So then the last equation is basically $v=f(x_1, x_2, v)$?

Comment: @user102938 No, you should think of that integral as a two variable function of $a$ and $b$. Setting it equal to zero then implicitly gives $b$ as a function of $a$. The $b$ in the final equation is referring to this function.

Comment: got you, thanks. So then $v=f(a,b)$ for some $a,b$. However from there, I'm a little unsure, how do we practically find the value for $v$? Say if we had for example $x_1=4$ and $x_2=5$

Comment: @user102938 I've edited the post to try to remove some of the ambiguity in how I used $b$. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: yes it makes much more sense, thank you. I see it basically comes down to finding the function $f$. I guess this means that there is no explicit solution for $v$ ?

Comment: @user102938 Well, if you think of $f$ as a new special function, then that's a closed form solution. Otherwise it doesn't appear so, but I could be wrong.